# Twitter Sign In using LINQ to twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, cors, twitter-oauth

I use LINQ to Twitter for authentication in my MVC application on localhost.

I configured my twitter app in the following way:
[image]

I implemented the controller using this article: https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Implementing%20OAuth%20for%20ASP.NET%20MVC&referringTitle=Learning%20to%20use%20OAuth 
and my methods BeginAsync and CompleteAsync are completely the same as in the article. But I keep getting an error `'XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<myToken>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access. '`

I added in Web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
      ...
  </system.webServer>
```

but it is still not working.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the guy from the article didn't use ajax requests. The twitter oauth api doesn't support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).